# Merge Spatial polygons from shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r

I have downloaded the shapefiles from the following website:

http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france.html

Each zip contains a "landuse" shapefile and I want to merge all of them in one single spatialpolygon object in R. My session crashes when executing the file, maybe because the memory gets full. Here is my code:

```
#directories of the shapefiles
directories <- list.dirs()

#read the first shapefile
shp.landuse <- readOGR(dsn=directories[1],
                  layer="landuse")

#merge all the shapefiles together
invisible(foreach(i=2:length(directories)) %do% {
temp <- readOGR(dsn=directories[i],
              layer="landuse")
shp.landuse <- rbind(shp.landuse,temp,makeUniqueIDs=TRUE)
}
)
```

Is there a better method? If it is indeed a RAM issue is it possible to store the data on a temporary database on the diskdrive instead than on the RAM?

Comment: Have you already had a look at `?maptools::spRbind`?

Comment: Hello,
This is the error message :
Error in { : task 1 failed - "non-unique polygon IDs"

Comment: Does your code work, and give you the expected result, if you try only two files to merge?

Comment: Hello, yes it does work. Also a detail worth knowing is that the maptools::spRbind works well for spatial points. It produces that error only for spatial polygons.

Comment: Have you checked if the error message is right and you have duplicate IDs in your polygons?